# Using futures and options to check if element exists in database and updating it

Tags: scala, redis, future

The issue I'm having is that I have elements being stored in Redis. I am trying to update a counter on an element that may not exist.

I have a function that will increment these values, and it has the return type of

```
def increment(id: String): Future[Option[Long]]
```

So, I make a call to see if the id exists. This has the return type of Future[Boolean]. If this boolean is False then I'd like to return None, and be done immediately. But, if the boolean is True then I'd like to make another call to increment my value, which has the return type Future[Long].

Here is some code of what I've tried:

```
for {
  exists <- redis.hExists(id, index) //returns Future[Boolean]
} yield if (exists) redis.hIncrBy(id, index, 1) //returns Future[Long]
  else None
```

Now I realize this doesn't work, but I'm at a loss of how to do this. I could wrap the None in a Future and then flatten the whole thing down and it should give me a Future[Option[Long]], but I feel like there has to be a better way to handle this kind of problem.

If anyone needs anymore information I'd be more than happy to clarify or explain anything I missed. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `Future.successful(None)`?

Comment: I was unaware this existed. Thank you Ryan.

Comment: FYI, `Future.successful` and `Future.failed` are pretty efficient since they don't actually involve an `ExecutionContext`, you aren't bouncing data around threads as you (potentially) are with `Future { ... }`.

Comment: That is great to know. I can't believe I'm just now finding out about these two helpful functions. Thanks a lot Ryan. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't really have an `Option` anywhere in that chain, you need to insert it somehow. Mapping the successful `Future` to `Some` should do it.

```
for {
    exists <- redis.hExists(id, index)
} yield {
   if (exists) redis.hIncrBy(id, index, 1).map(Some(_))
   else Future.successful(None)
}
```

Comment: Thank you m-z. Future.successful(None) is exactly what I was looking for.